# JPA doesn't t allow entity made of columns from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I know this makes none sense as many tutorials state that you can use SecondaryTable annotation, however it doesn't work in hibernate. I have schema like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="server")
@SecondaryTable(name="cluster", pkJoinColumns = { @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "uuid", referencedColumnName = "cluster_uuid") })
public class Server {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "cluster_uuid")
    private String clusterUuid;

      @Column(name = "ip", table="cluster")
      private String ip;
..... }

@Entity
@Table(name = "cluster")
public class Cluster {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "ip")
    private String ip;

.....
}
```

Server.clusterUuid is a foreign key to Cluster.uuid. **I am hoping to get Server entity that fetches ip column from Cluster by joining Server.clusterUuid to Cluster.uuid.**

Then I was greeted by a hibernate exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: SecondaryTable
>   JoinColumn cannot reference a non primary key
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:402)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.bindJoinToPersistentClass(EntityBinder.java:620)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.createPrimaryColumnsToSecondaryTable(EntityBinder.java:612)

I see lots of people encountered this problem. But the first bug for this in Hibernate's bugzilla was 2010, I am surprised it's been there for over two years as this is supposed to be a basic feature. There is some post saying JPA spec only allows primary key to do the mapping, however, I get below from JPA wikibook

> JPA allows multiple tables to be assigned to a single class. The
>   @SecondaryTable and SecondaryTables annotations or 
>   elements can be used. By default the @Id column(s) are assumed to be
>   in both tables, such that the secondary table's @Id column(s) are the
>   primary key of the table **and a foreign key to the first table**. If
>   the first table's @Id column(s) are not named the same the
>   @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn or  can be used to
>   define the foreign key join condition.

it's obviously OK for non-primary key. Then I am confused why Hibernate didn't fix this problem as it seems to be easy to implement by a join clause.

anybody knows how to overcome this problem? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your setup.

`@SecondaryTable` is for storing a single entity in multiple tables, but in your case you have a many-to-one relationship between different entities (each one stored in its own table), and it should be mapped as such:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="server") 
public class Server { 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cluster_uuid")
    private Cluster cluster;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't say clearly. I have editted the stuff, actually I need one column from Cluster rather than whole Cluster entity wired in Server. So I  think ManyToOne won't work for me

Comment: @zx_wing: I don't think it's a good idea anyway. If you need `ip` of a `Server`, create a getter that would get it from the related `Cluster`.