# JPA: how to composite an entity from columns of multiple tables (not save an entity to mulitple tables)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableA")
public class TableA {
     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     long id;

     @Column(name="tableB_id")
     long tbId;

     @Column(name="column1", table="TableB")
     String tbColumn1; 
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TableB")
public class TableB {
     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     long id;

     @Column(name="column1")
     String column1; 
}
```

TableA has a foreign key 'tbId' to TableB.id. And TableB has a column named "column1", now I want to get "column1" in TableA entity by some sort of join. What's way I should go in terms of JPA? This is not OneToOne as I don't want to wire entire TableB entity in TableA.

Comment: Did you consider database VIEW or JPA Construct Query?

Comment: You just want to use it for Reading, not Modifying, right?

Comment: I think you need the @SecondaryTable annotation: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables

Comment: @JMelnik, yes only for read. I don't want VIEW as it introduces other complex. What's construct query?

Comment: @McIntosh. SecondaryTable doesn't work. see my another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305977/jpa-doesnt-t-allow-entity-made-of-columns-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to group columns within one object only for reading data I suggest you two ways:

1. Creating DB VIEW and map it as an Entity.
2. Using [Result Classes Constructor Expression](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_), it will instantiate and populate objects of provided class based on results query return.

From ObjectDB on Result Classes Constructor Expression:

> JPA supports wrapping JPQL query results with instances of custom
>   result classes. This is mainly useful for queries with multiple SELECT
>   expressions, where custom result objects can provide an object
>   oriented alternative to representing results as Object[] elements.