# named native query and mapping columns to field of entity that doesn't exist in table

Tags: jpa

I have a named native query and I am trying to map it to the return results of the named native query.  There is a field that I want to add to my entity that doesn't exist in the table, but it will exist in the return result of the query.  I guess this would be the same with a stored proc...

How do you map the return results of a stored proc in JPA?...

How do you even call a stored proc?

here is an example query of what I would like to do...

```
select d.list_id as LIST_ID, 0 as Parent_ID, d.description  from EPCD13.distribution_list d
```

The Result will be mapped to this entity...

```
public class DistributionList implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="LIST_ID")
    private long listId;

    private String description;

    private String owner;

    private String flag;

    @Column(name="PARENT_ID", nullable = true)
    private long parentID;
}
```

parent ID is not in any table in my database.  I will also need to use this entity again for other calls, that have nothing to do with this call, and that will not need this parent_id?  Is there anything in the JPA standard that will help me out?

Comment: Do you need to manipulate the retrieved entity later?

Comment: I will basically just be throwing this back at the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If results from database are not required for further manipulation, just for preview, you can consider using [database view or result classes constructor expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320586/jpa-how-to-composite-an-entity-from-columns-of-multiple-tables-not-save-an-ent).

---

If entities retrieved from database are required for further manipulation, you can make use of [multiple select expression](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Multiple_SELECT_Expressions_) and [transient fields](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/fields#Transient_Fields_).

1. Replace @Column annotation with @Transient annotation over parentID.
2. After retrieving multiple columns from database, iterate over results and manually set parentID.

Comment: What will be the result set that I will be looping over?  I was thinking object, but I don't think that will work... How do I loop over the result set.

Comment: @DmainEvent result depends on what kind of select do you use, read links above I posted. It can be Object[] and Tuple.